php-fpm taking too much CPU utilization
We have configured 3 instances behind a load balancer powering our backend running php on them. All three instances have same configurations. Everything was working fine but suddenly one of the three instances started taking much more CPU Utilisation than the other two. On investigating on NewRelic I found out that the load is not being divided equally on all three instances. On one of the VMs php-fpm process is taking 5x the CPU% while catering to only 1/4th of the total traffic.
On running HTOP, I can clearly see that the php-fpm process is taking way more CPU usage than on the other VMs running the same application with same configurations and catering more traffic.
Earlier, everything was symmetrical. All three instances divided the traffic equally and the php-fpm process didn't take this much CPU usage(as in the case of other 2 VMs).
So during times of high traffic the CPU Utilisation is spiking to 90-100% on that particular VM meanwhile the others are running at 10%.
I can't seem to wrap my head around what could have gone wrong and why is that VM behaving weirdly since I did not change any configuration.
Running sudo service php8.1-fpm restart is not helping too.

Check if you accidentally enabled xdebug on that one.

If the configurations of your VMs are truly identical (same hardware specs, identical config options) this would suggest that either a) your load balancer's config somehow favors that machine or b) the traffic that happens to get routed to that one machine is such that it prompts more CPU-intensive requests. You might try comparing the web server logs on the busy machine to the other ones. I don't know how your load balancer's algorithm distributes traffic, but it may be routing googlebot to that machine or something.
